# API VK Получение списка сообществ

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Здравствуйте. Мне нужна помощь в API VK. 
Я получаю с помощью метода сообщества, они приходят мне в формате JSON, как мне сделать так, чтобы как только нажимаешь на кнопку `Получить список сообществ` тебе выдавался оформленный список с Названием сообщества, фотографией сообщества и число подписчиков?
Вот код :

```
$fields = [
'id', 'name', 'screen_name', 'photo_100'
];

$request_params = [
    'user_id' => '43859597',
    'extended' => '0',
    'filter' => 'admin',
    'fields' => implode(',', $fields),
    'access_token' => 'ТОКЕН',
    'count' => '150',

];

$url = "https://api.vk.com/method/groups.get?" . http_build_query($request_params);

$result = file_get_contents($url);
echo '<p><a href="'. $url .'">Получить список сообществ</a></p>';
```

Хочу , чтобы я получал список в таком формате :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: на клиенте формировать хтмл. можно из пхп, можно из джс

Comment: А где можно поподробнее узнать, как это делается?

Comment: Просто почитай про вывод информации из PHP, а также про оформления html тегов с помощью CSS

Comment: @erm , мне нужно вывести информацию из JSON ответа.

Comment: JSON можно поместить в массив с помощью `json_decode`. А потом массив выводит в любом виде. Если зайти в гугл, то полно статей по расшарингу постов на странице сайта. Тут помогут подправить пример, а не написать код.

Comment: @erm, поместил, но теперь выдается ошибка `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`. Правильно ли я поместил? Вот код ` $decode = json_decode($result); echo $decode;`

Comment: Массив выводят через print_r

Comment: @erm, спасибо большое. Сейчас попробую, может получится что нибудь сделать.

Comment: @erm, все получилось, спасибо. Хочу кое что еще узнать. Я получаю результат от `json_decode` , там есть количество подписчиков для каждой из групп. Как собственно сделать, чтобы складывались все подписчики из всех сообществ и выводились? Для вывода сообществ использовал `foreach`

Comment: С помощью foreach пробегаетесь по массиву и с каждого достаете количество участников, параллельно складывая в отдельную переменную.

Comment: @erm, а с помощью чего можно их сложить в отдельную переменную?
`foreach ($decode->response as $result)`  `$members_count = $result->members_count;` - это переменная достает значения подписчиков.

Comment: А потом внутри цикла $count += $members_count

Comment: @erm, большое тебе спасибо!!!